# Asterisk Playback Sound just from CLI

Tags: command-line-interface, asterisk, playback

I m using a Starface application based on Asteric. I aim for injecting a soundfile into a broadcast to several channels.

how can i execute the playback() command in the CLI for a specific channel. 
The Starface application overwrites the dialplans (extensions.config). Therefor it is not possible to configure the *.config files.

I hope anyone can help me

lpc

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 options

1) User AMI event listener and user ChannelRedirect action when needed

2)(correct one) change your application.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a callfile to a local channel with an application invocation:

Channel: local/100@context

Application: Playback

Data: soundfile

context:

exten => 100,1,page(SIP/tele1&SIP/tele2)